# Scanner isn't recognized in my all in one printer

Tags: printing, scanner

I have a wireless HP deskjet 2652 all in one scanner/printer. I tried the HPlip download, and it says no devices are found. The general printer driver picks up on the printer, but nothing is picking up on the scanner. How do I get the scanner to work?

Comment: might help to say what version of Ubuntu you are using...

Comment: Did you tried simple scan?

Answer (score 0):

The new upgrade to 17.10 fixed it.